# Different hibernate modes on MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, mojave, battery, hibernate

Sorry if this question will appear to be stupid.
Is it possible to set one hibernate mode (for example 3) when macbook is on power adapter and another hibernate mode (25) when it’s on battery. Is it absolutely nonsense or...? hehe
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can set different hibernation modes with `pmset`.

Most articles on the subject give the command `pmset -a hibernatemode X` (where X is a number). The `-a` flag is for 'all' modes: you can alternatively set `-b` for battery and `-c` for charger.

Whether there's any benefit in doing so, is another matter! Modern RAM is quite efficient, and you're not likely to reap significant battery time savings: you'll just slow down the sleep and wake processes. The 25 setting was used in much older laptops.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So, there is no point in changing hibernate mode? But my Macbook drains sometimes battery during sleep... Maybe I need to experiment with standby delay?

Comment: @KirillBara What model of Mac is it? Is Powernap turned off? How much battery are you losing? There are quite a lot of questions about battery running down during sleep, so check them out and then ask a question about that if necessary.

Comment: MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2019), 2,3 GHz Intel Core i9. Power Nap is off as default. I'm losing ~5% per night. I've checked "wake up" tasks - there were nothing. I really don't what's the problem :) And also I've lost 11% of my battery capacity this year. P.S. I am still on Mojave...

Comment: The 11% is worrying. Might be worth taking it in to an Apple Store.